# Round string before converting to numeric type

Tags: c#, string

I have a number (just an example:

```
"3616,946489653802082229919075063226"
```

stored in a `string`. I want to convert it into `decimal` but get an **OverflowException** because the value is too long for decimal.

I want to *round* the `string` before converting it *to fix the error*.

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you try it? Please provide your code. SO will help you if you get stuck, but it's not a code providing service.

Comment: How are you converting it? `Decimal.Parse("3616.946489653802082229919075063226")` works on my machine, while `Decimal.Parse("3616,946489653802082229919075063226")` gives me a `FormatException` because the `,` is interpreted as a thousands separator, but an `OverflowException` is not in the cards.

Comment: I tried converting your sample using `Convert.ToDecimal("...")` and it correctly converted it. I only get an `OverflowException`, when the number is too big for a `decimal`...

Comment: What is the expected result? Should it be `3616.9464896538020822299190751`?

Comment: @NicoSchreiner are you sure? https://dotnetfiddle.net/0uu1rk - it produces the error stated in the question. If you change the comma to a dot then it's ok: https://dotnetfiddle.net/828rxL . Is that what you did?

Comment: `decimal result = decimal.Parse(source, new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = ","});`

Comment: @ADyson yes it does. Copy pasted the code you linked into VS and it converts it to 3616.9464896538020822299190751. Ahh the problem is culture...

Comment: @NicoSchreiner have you got a different culture setting in your app maybe?

Comment: @ADyson yes the culture is the problem. My culture is de-DE and we use ',' as a separator.

Comment: @NicoSchreiner that explains it then. Maybe that's something worth writing up as an answer - OP might be lacking the culture setting in their app which they would need, if they want to deal with this kind of format as standard. or they might prefer one of the answers below where they hard-code the separator in to the code in order to deal with this as if it's a special case. I think showing how to set the culture and then do the conversion as normal ought to be a valid option here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parsing is culture specific. So `,` can be either decimal or thousand separator. If `,` is a thousand separator, it will be *ignored*:

```
"3616,946489653802082229919075063226" -> 3616946489653802082229919075063226m
```

And this value is over `decimal.MaxValue` so you have the *exception thrown*.

If `,` should be treated as a decimal separator, let system know it:

```
decimal result = decimal.Parse(source, 
  new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = ","});
```

And you'll get `3616.9464896538020822299190751m`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not actually a rounding issue, it is trying to parse a decimal with a comma on a system which expects a dot as a decimal separator by default.

You could try this to make sure it is parsed well on all environments:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = "3616,946489653802082229919075063226";
        var result = decimal.Parse(input, new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = ","});
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8iaL9d

Answer (score 0):

Given an arbitrary number of decimal places in a format with a comma separating the units from the fractional part, you could solve it by doing the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var decimalPlacesCount = 10;
        var decimalSeparator = ',';
        var parts = "3616,946489653802082229919075063226".Split(decimalSeparator);
        var value = decimal.Parse(parts[0]);
        if (parts.Length == 2)
        {
            value += decimal.Parse($"0.{parts[1].Substring(0, decimalPlacesCount)}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

This effectively rounds it to decimalPlacesCount.

Answer (score 0):

While this wasn't your problem if anyone happens to stumble across this well-named question looking for a method that will actually round a string hopefully, the following will be helpful.

```
    public static string RoundString(string value, int decimalPlaces)
    {
        StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder(value);

        int startIndex = 0;

        int charIndex = 0;
        while (charIndex < value.Length && startIndex == 0)
        {
            if (value[charIndex].ToString() == ".")
                startIndex = charIndex + 1;

            charIndex++;
        }

        if (int.Parse(value[charIndex + decimalPlaces + 1].ToString()) >= 5)
        {
            bool rounded = false;
            for (charIndex = startIndex + decimalPlaces; charIndex > -1; charIndex--)
            {
                if (!rounded && charIndex != startIndex-1)
                { 
                    int newVal = int.Parse(returnValue[charIndex].ToString()) + 1;
                    if (newVal > 9)
                    {
                        returnValue[charIndex] = '0';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        returnValue[charIndex] = (int.Parse(returnValue[charIndex].ToString()) + 1).ToString()[0];
                        rounded = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!rounded)
            {
                startIndex++;
                returnValue = new StringBuilder("1" + returnValue.ToString());
            }
        }

        return returnValue.ToString().Substring(0, startIndex + decimalPlaces);
    }
```

It's pretty poorly written and I'm sure someone could do better, but it does the job. The StringBuilder is pretty shoddy for example and it can likely be made to run quicker.

Also, I do 0 validation on the actual input string.